# Get any parameter from a Post Method in a Web Api controller

Tags: c#, .net, post, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I've an old page made in aspx that get every `Request.Form.Keys` and made a POST using a form to another page (is like an "HTTP POST REDIRECT")

Now this system must be migrated to Web API (2.1) and I must emulate the same.

The trick with this is that the aspx gets any/multiple keys and values, you can post anything to the aspx. But I can't get the same result with my POST method in web api, because it expects the object as is (and I don't know it and I don't care)

I don't know if this can help, but the code of the old aspx is like this one:

```
        sb.Append("<html>");
        sb.AppendFormat("<body onload='document.forms[0].submit()'>Loading...");
        sb.AppendFormat("<form action='{0}' method='post'>",
            the-next-url);
        foreach (string key in Request.Form.Keys)
        {
            sb.AppendFormat("<input type='hidden' name='{0}' value='{1}'>", key, Request.Form[key]);
        }
        sb.Append("</form>");
        sb.Append("</body>");
        sb.Append("</html>");

        Response.Write(sb.ToString());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could refactor your code, I suppose, to use something like this:

```
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.Count > 0)
        {
            sb.Append("<html>");
            sb.AppendFormat("<body onload='document.forms[0].submit()'>Loading...");
            sb.AppendFormat("<form action='{0}' method='post'>",your_url);
            foreach (string key in HttpContext.Current.Request.Form.AllKeys)
            {
                sb.AppendFormat("<input type='hidden' name='{0}' value='{1}'>", key,
                    HttpContext.Current.Request.Form[key]);
            }
            sb.Append("</form>");
            sb.Append("</body>");
            sb.Append("</html>");



        }
```

Comment: Thanks! I used a process similar

Answer (score 4):

Finally, I just use inside my method:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Form
```

to get all POST keys and values instead of `Request.Form`